# Unable to test a Golang CLI tool's output

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I have a cli tool written in Go which produces the following output:

```
  Command: config get
      Env: int
Component: foo-component

Unable to find any configuration within Cosmos (http://api.foo.com) for foo-component.
```

I would like to verify this output within a test.

The test I have written (and doesn't pass) is as follows:

```
package command

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/my/package/foo"
)

type FakeCliContext struct{}

func (s FakeCliContext) String(name string) string {
    return "foobar"
}

func ExampleInvalidComponentReturnsError() {
    fakeBaseURL := "http://api.foo.com"
    fakeCliContext := &FakeCliContext{}
    fakeFetchFlag := func(foo.CliContext) (map[string]string, error) {
        return map[string]string{
            "env":       "int",
            "component": "foo-component",
        }, nil
    }

    GetConfig(*fakeCliContext, fakeFetchFlag, fakeBaseURL)

    // Output:
    //   Command: config get
    //       Env: int
    // Component: foo-component
    //
    // Unable to find any configuration within Cosmos (http://api.foo.com) for foo-component.
}
```

The majority of the code is creating fake objects that I'm injecting into my function call `GetConfig`.

Effectively there is no return value from `GetConfig` only a side effect of text being printed to stdout.

So I'm using the `Example<NameOfTest>` format to try and verify the output.

But all I just back when I run `go test -v` is:

```
=== RUN   ExampleInvalidComponentReturnsError
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/my/package/thing 0.418s
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

I've found that if I add an additional test after the 'Example' one above, for example called `Test<NameOfTest>` (but consistenting of effectively the same code), then this will actually display the function's output into my stdout when running the test:

```
func TestInvalidComponentReturnsError(t *testing.T) {
    fakeBaseURL := "http://api.foo.com"
    fakeCliContext := &FakeCliContext{}
    fakeFetchFlag := func(utils.CliContext) (map[string]string, error) {
        return map[string]string{
            "env":       "int",
            "component": "foo-component",
        }, nil
    }

    GetConfig(*fakeCliContext, fakeFetchFlag, fakeBaseURL)
}
```

The above example test will now show the following output when executing `go test -v`:

```
=== RUN   TestInvalidComponentReturnsError
  Command: config get
      Env: int
Component: foo-component

Unable to find any configuration within Cosmos (http://api.foo.com) for foo-component.
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/bbc/apollo/command   0.938s
```

Comment: I suspect it is a buffering issue. Are you writing to Stdout and how are you capturing the output to verify it in the test?

Comment: @StuartCarnie hmm, I've just realised that I'm executing `output.Error` and that internally is calling `os.Exit(1)`. That is likely not helping

Comment: @StuartCarnie that's exactly the problem. If I comment out `os.Exit(1)` then the command will display the error (same as before) but now it shows either `null` or `[]` depending on the type of error triggered. But it does mean the `// Output:` is actually failing because the output isn't quite the same (e.g. it's adding an extra line for `null` or `[]`)

Comment: So I need to figure out how to either keep `os.Exit(1)` in place and swap it out during the test with a mock OR remove it permanently and figure out how to handle the response `null` and `[]`

Comment: Have your functions return errors, and only call log.Fatal or os.Exit in main(). You can then unit test your functions without having to mock anything.

Comment: without seeing your code, I can't comment on the `os.Exit(1)` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the solution to this problem was part architecture and part removal/refactor of code.

1. I extracted the private functions from the cli command package so they became public functions in a separate function
2. I refactored the code so that all dependencies were injected, this then allowed me to mock these objects and verify the the expected methods were called
3. Now the private functions are in a package and made public, I'm able to test those things specifically, outside of the cli context
4. Finally, I removed the use of os.Exit as that was a nightmare to deal with and wasn't really necessary